# Gathering bans and Churches

Tags: united-states, religion

With bans on gatherings due to the virus, can the government close churches or are they exempt due to seperation laws?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Free Exercise Clause of the First Amendment requires government restrictions on churches to satisfy a compelling government interest, such as preventing massive deaths from disease. The Establishment Clause of the First Amendment prohibits the government from granting special privileges to a specific religion or to all religions ([Everson v. Board of Education](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/330/1/), 330 U.S. 1 – government may not "pass laws which aid one religion, aid all religions or prefer one religion over another").

Exempting only religious gatherings (however defined) would be unconstitutional. Restricting *all* gatherings (including religious gatherings) would be constitutional (subject to the general restrictions being itself constitutional).

Comment: In short: "separation of church and state" does not mean churches are exempt from regulation - it just means they must not get _special_ treatment (i.e. neither better nor worse than other organizations).